# How to capitalize the first letter of specific words in a document?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm modifying a Google-apps-script to create meeting minutes(google doc) from google calendar events. For reasons, rather than importing the name of participants, I have to import their emails and modify the text to make it appear as names. Here is a link to the result (can't post images yet) : [Both the first name and last name are completely in lowercase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viLt1.png) I have no idea how to capitalize the first letter of the First and Last name. Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
function createMeetingNotesNextTimePeriod() {

    // variables for text format
    var emailString = '@companyname';
    var deleteString = '';
    var repEmail = 'test';
    var dot = '\[.]';
    var spaceString = ' ';
    var repDot = 'test2'; 

    // retrieve all calendar events for time period with @notes string
    var events = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getEvents(now, period_from_now, {search: '@notes'}) ; 
    // loop through each event an get meeting attributes, 
    for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
      var title = events[i].getTitle();
      var eventstart = events[i].getStartTime();
      var eventend = events[i].getEndTime();
      var location = events[i].getLocation();
      var owner = events[i].getCreators();
      var ordredujour = events[i].getDescription();
      var guestlist = events[i].getGuestList();

      // create a google doc with the meeting name as the title       
      var doc = DocumentApp.create(title);

      //write the description of the meeting 
      doc.getBody().editAsText()
      .insertText(0, '\n' + 'Ordre du jour:  ' + ordredujour + '\n\n');               

      //writes the email adresses of the guests
      for (var j=0;j<guestlist.length;j++) {
      var name = guestlist[j].getEmail();
      var guestStatus = guestlist[j].getGuestStatus();
      doc.getBody().editAsText()
      .insertText(0, name + ': ' + guestStatus +'\n')
      }

      //Write Guests
      doc.getBody().editAsText()
      .insertText(0, 'Invités:\n');

      //Write the name of the organiser 
      doc.getBody().editAsText()
      .insertText(0, 'Organisateur:  ' + owner + '\n\n' );

      //writes the location of the meeting
      doc.getBody().editAsText()
      .insertText(0, 'Location:  ' + location + '\n\n');

      //writes the meeting ending time
      doc.getBody().editAsText()
      .insertText(0, 'Fin:  ' + eventend + '\n\n');

      //writes the meeting starting time
      doc.getBody().editAsText()
      .insertText(0, 'Début:  ' + eventstart + '\n');

      //writes the title of the meeting
      doc.getBody().editAsText()
      .insertText(0, '\n\n' + title + '\n\n')
      .setFontSize(0, title.length+1, 14)
      .setBold(0, title.length+1, true)
      .setForegroundColor(0, title.length+1, '#cc0000');

      //replacement of "@companyname.com" and "." 
      Logger.log(repEmail.replace(emailString, deleteString)); 
      Logger.log(repEmail.replace(new RegExp(emailString), deleteString)); 
      doc.replaceText(emailString,deleteString);
      Logger.log(doc.getText());

      Logger.log(repDot.replace(dot, spaceString)); 
      Logger.log(repDot.replace(new RegExp(dot), spaceString)); 
      doc.replaceText(dot,spaceString);

    }  // for loop for each event 

}  // functionCreateMeetingNotesNextTimePeriod
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plese try below code

```
doc.getBody().editAsText()
      .insertText(0, name.split(" ")[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ")[0].slice(1) + ' ' + name.split(" ")[1].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ")[1].slice(1)  + ': ' + guestStatus +'\n')
      }
```

instead of

```
 doc.getBody().editAsText()
      .insertText(0, name + ': ' + guestStatus +'\n')
      }
```

it may work for you.

Comment: I tried your code and it looks promising. However, it says there is a TypeError since we can't use the charAt method for an undefined element. So I'm guessing I have to change it to a string type.

Comment: logic behind my code is that it is splitting name with space and then it takes first character of each and make it capital...So is there any condition where you receive only First name(or name without space) ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I left that crucial part out. The name first appears as an email address, for example: john.smith@companyname.com. Later in the code I used replaceText to delete @companyname.com and and transform the "." into a space. I will edit the question to include this part. Thank you again for your help and patience.

Comment: @Plz_dont_hate I reviewed your question and I guess you above code will work if you are getting name data like "FirstName LastName".